# How to get the referencing function pointer in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a LLVM module pass that will get the third argument in `pthread_create`. According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) the function prototype of `pthread_create` is

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

For example my target C source is as following.

```
  void *pthread_task(void *args) {
    sleep(4);
    return NULL;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, pthread_task, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
  }
```

I would like to have the output "pthread_task". I was able to access the right function and list all arguments. However, since the third parameter is a function pointer, I don't know how to access the function which it points to.

Also I attach how I implement my module pass as following.

```
  namespace {
~   int32_t indexOfPthreadCreate(CallGraphNode *node) {
~     for (int32_t i = 0; i < node -> size(); i++) {
~       Function *f = (*node)[i] -> getFunction();
~       if (f && f -> getName().compare("pthread_create") == 0) {
+         for (auto &A: f->args()) {

            // I would like to access the third parameter of pthread_create here.

+           A.print(errs());
+         }
+         return i;
+       }
      }
~     return -1;
    }
    struct PthreadScopeDetectPass : public ModulePass {
      static char ID;
      PthreadScopeDetectPass() : ModulePass(ID) { }

      bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {
        CallGraph &CG = getAnalysis<CallGraphWrapperPass>().getCallGraph();
        uint32_t nSCC  = 0;
        for (scc_iterator<CallGraph *> iterSCC = scc_begin(&CG); !iterSCC.isAtEnd(); ++iterSCC) {
          auto nodes = *iterSCC;
          for (CallGraphNode *node: nodes) {
            Function *currFunc = node -> getFunction();
~           int32_t target_i = indexOfPthreadCreate(node);
~           if (target_i > 0 && currFunc) {
+             insertTimer(currFunc);
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
        AU.setPreservesAll();
        AU.addRequired<CallGraphWrapperPass>();
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: That's available in the CallBase, which IIRC isn't recorded in the CallGraph (again, *IIRC*). You can walk the calling functions and find the CallBase instructions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @arnt's comment. I already solve the issue. Here's how I solve it.

```
~   int32_t indexOfPthreadCreate(CallGraphNode *node) {
~     for (int32_t i = 0; i < node -> size(); i++) {
~       Function *f = (*node)[i] -> getFunction();
~       if (f && f -> getName().compare("pthread_create") == 0) {
+         for (auto &inst: instructions(f)) {
~           if (inst.getOpcode() == 56) {
~             CallInst *ci = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&inst);
~             if (ci && ci->getCalledFunction()->getName().compare("pthread_create") == 0) {
~               Function *pthread_task = dyn_cast<Function>(ci->getArgOperand(2));
~_              errs() << "pthread is going to execute " << pthread_task->getName() << "function \n";
              }
+           }
+           A.print(errs());
+         }
+         return i;
+       }
      }
~     return -1;
    }
```